# Multiple daemons init script

Tags: opensuse, init-script, daemon, init.d

I have two daemons currently running on my development server (OpenSUSE 12).
There are two daemon that work together as a whole and must start together and die together.

1. Is there a standard way to accomplish such a thing with init scripts ?
2. Should I create an init script for each one of them, or should they be in the same script ?
3. Is there some kind of service that can check if both the daemons are running and if one is not restart both of them ?